# R: surface of spineplot and spineplot with log y-axis

Tags: r

I have two questions regarding the spineplot function in R. (A spineplot plots P(Y|x) vs. x).

1. I need to find out the surface under the spineplot. With other words, can I extract the width and height of the bars that spineplot() creates somehow?
2. Is there anyway to make the y-axis logarithmic?

Thank you! Frauke